# Is it possible to exclude a dict path in deepdiff without knowing the keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 dicts which I want to get the diff of them. For this I use the [deepDiff module](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is extremly good. It's possible to add the arg "exclude_paths" but the problem is I want to exclude a Path which I dont know because my dicts are soo big.

Like:

```
root['thiskeyiknow']['idontknowthiskey']['idontknowthiskey']['iknowthiskey']
```

so is there a way to exclude all paths which are like this:

```
root['thiskeyiknow']['everykeyispossiblehere']['everykeyispossiblehere']['thiskeyshouldbeexcluded']
```

in unix it would be the * which means everything ... is there something in python which says: "here can be anything just put it in?"

I already tried something like this:

```
root['key1']['']['']['keyiwanttoexclude']
```

but it didn't work.

So if I have a dict like this:

```
dict1 = {"key1":{key2:{key3:{key4: "bla"}}}}
dict2 = {"key1":{key2:{key3:{key4: "fasl"}}}}


excludePaths = [

    "root['key1'][all][all]['key4']"

]

diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict1,dict2,exclude_paths=excludePaths)
```

Output should be:

```
{}
```

Output shouldn't be:

```
{" root['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']" : {

'new_value' = 'bla'
'old_value' = 'fasl'

}
```

Comment: Use `exclude_regex_paths` instead?

Comment: Okay how does it works? Is there a doc for it?

Comment: Of course [there is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and many tutorials out there too.

Comment: Okay now I found one thank you very much :) in the newst doc of 4.0.7 there is no exclude_regex_paths mentioned :(

Comment: I don't know what doc you mean, I found it by following your link and then clicking "DeepDiff Reference".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I was able to do it.

Solution:

Make a list with the exluded regex strings:

exp:

```
excludedRegex = [
     r"root['key1'][.+?][.+?]['key4']"
     etc.
]
```

and then add the excluding list to the deepdict

```
diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict1,dict2,exclude_regex_paths=excludeRegex)
```

and thats all it takes

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the key in any path? I don't know the path, but I would like to ignore the key in the dictionary or sub dictionary inside it. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean without deepdict, I dont think so ... searched for it a lot but the only things i found were for loops + check if a key is there or not ...

Comment: Pretty sure, he meant with deepdiff. Without knowing the depth of the path. E.g. something like - `r"root[ANY_PATH_DEPTH_HERE_WITHOUT_SPECIFYING_HOW_MANY]['key4']"`

Comment: @Jason 
something like `root(\[\'\w+\'\])*\['key1'\]` should work.
If you need to further specify the path just add other `\['keyYouNeed'\]` in there.